How to prevent default route being set when consuming SLAAC?
On a Debian 12 VM I have 2 network interfaces set up, namely eth0 and eth1. Both interfaces have access to the Internet and set up for SLAAC autoconfiguration.
Since both networks have a router, my routing table on this VM ends up looking like this:
2a01:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64 dev eth1 proto kernel metric 256 expires 86388sec pref medium
fd45:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 expires 2591988sec pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth1 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx dev eth1 proto ra metric 1024 expires 1788sec hoplimit 64 pref medium
default via fe80::be24:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx dev eth0 proto ra metric 1024 expires 1788sec pref medium

On the first few days everything was fine, and I can access internal content in fd45:: through eth0. However it suddenly broke now, with all outbound traffic routed through eth1, as described by traceroute.
I want to force outbound connections to use eth0. I can temporarily remove the default route on eth1 by using ip -6 route del default dev eth1 but it would come back in a few minutes. Is there any way I could achieve this?
My /etc/network/interfaces looks like this:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet6 auto

iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface eth0 inet6 auto


In what way is traffic going out eth1 broken?  What destinations can you not reach?  What security policy is not getting enforced?

@JohnMahowald eth1 is an interface I only want to use for receiving incoming connection. I am unable to reach fd45:: through eth1 (as there is no route to that range, which is expected), while 2a01:: is also available on eth0.

With the kernel's built-in SLAAC client, set the sysctl:
net.ipv6.conf.eth1.accept_ra_defrtr = 0

With systemd-networkd's SLAAC client, configure in the .network file:
[IPv6AcceptRA]
UseGateway=false

